# Can search engines change language and read the cookie?

Tags: search-engines, cookie, multilingual

I am building a multi language website in PHP and prepared all my strings in English by default using `gettext()`
My locale/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo file is working correctly and now I need to sort out the language detection and switching.

I was thinking about using the approach with the GET parameter:

```
<a href="?locale=en_US">English</a> | <a href="?locale=it_IT">Italian</a>
```

I also thought that writing the parameter in a cookie should be better than in PHP's `$_SESSION`

```
$locale = "it_IT"; // default in Italian
if (isset($_GET["locale"])) {
    $locale = $_GET["locale"];
    setcookie("locale", $locale, time()+60*60*24*365*10, "/"); // for 10 years
}
if (!$locale && isset($_COOKIE["locale"])) {
    $locale = $_COOKIE["locale"];
}

// locales directory
$locales_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/locale"; 
$domain = "default";
// activate the locale setting
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
// bind it, than activate
bindtextdomain($domain, $locales_root);
textdomain($domain);
```

OK so far, so good.
Now my actual question……
How can a search engine index the English content? It follows the "?locale=en_US" link, than what?
Does the cookie get written? The first page is translated fine, but I am not adding the GET parameter to all my links.
I saw this on some websites before; when you change the language the URL changes to somewebsite.com/it/ (mode_rewrite?) and the next click it's not added anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the locale all the time in the url?

Like `http://yousite.com/en/index.php` and `/it/index.php`?

This effectively solves your problem.

Comment: How can I implement this? Do I need to pull it from the URL?

Comment: It mostly depends on your code. Do you use a framework? Most frameworks support this kind of thing easily by modifying their routing settings. Look in Google for "clean urls" for some introduction to this, or ask on StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: John, I know how to use mod_rewrite, actually I am already re-writing that's why I would avoid going with your suggestion... but I am going to have to I guess. Just been reading 2 interesting articles: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html , http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html Now I just need to wrap my head around how I am going to add the GET parameter to all my links.

Comment: And I don't use a framework, just Apache/mySQL/PHP

Comment: You could try using php 's auto_prepend ini setting (if I understood correctly what you want to do).

Comment: I was just thinking... what if I just localize my links with gettext() like so: <?= _('<a href="it/contact">test locale contact</a>'); ?> Than pick it up with mod-rewrite. What do you think about this?

Comment: I'd recommend against URL vars for implementing multilanguage sites. They're hard to use for people and prevent geotargetting in google webmaster tools. See 'url structures' table: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.dk/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html

Answer (score 1):

Search engines do not parse any content hidden behind a cookie. Also, hardly ever do they read content presented by a javascript (sometimes Google does).

I suggest having a look at the Yii framework, it is pretty easy for beginners, it will answer many questions, and will save you lots of trouble.